# Reasoning behind Disciplined Badge

Tags: discussion

As I understand, the badges in a Stack Exchange site are curated by site moderators and thus vary across sites (Please correct me if I am wrong).

I have difficulty understanding the reasoning behind certain badges. One among those badges is the **Disciplined badge**.

---

[image]

---

What could possibly be the intent behind deleting a well received post?

Comment: I think badges are created by Stack Exchange programmers and are not under moderator control definitions and requests and chnages are discussed in meta.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> It's disciplined because you delete the post even though you will lose rep by doing so - i.e. you actually care more about answer correctness and relevance than rep (or, as smackfu says, you care enough about badges that it pushes you over the line (gives you enough incentive to delete your answer, knowing you will get an extra badge out of it).

From [What is the purpose of the “disciplined” badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7609/222623) where there are other answers that might be worth a read, there's many reasons a post should be deleted and this gives an incentive to do that when it is justified rather than thinking too much about your reputation loss.

Badges are consistent across all sites and not in control of the site moderators. Changes to badges can be discussed and coordinated with the Stack Exchange community on Meta Stack Exchange.